# Solve this: $\frac{dx}{dt} = [a-(b+c)]x-ax^2$ by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this equation

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = [a-(b+c)]x-ax^2$$

which I need to solve by separation of variables. I've never seen an example like this where you have a sum on the RHS of the eq. Usually the examples are just a product on the RHS.

I have the initial condition of $x(0)=x_0$

Comment: "Usually the examples are just a product on the RHS." The RHS **is** a product, namely $x\cdot(a-b-c-ax)$.

Comment: True but I can't totally factor out the x. I'm just being dumb with this tbh. I need to revise D.E. from last term - I've totally forgotten everything lol.

Comment: $$\frac u{x(u-x)}=\frac1x+\frac a{u-ax}=\left(\log|x|-\log|u-ax|\right)'=\left(\log\left|\frac x{u-ax}\right|\right)'$$

Answer (score -1):

Separation of variables means putting everything in $x$ on one side and $t$ on the other, then integrating:

**NOTE** I will replace $dx$ with $dX$ and $dt$ with $T$ to avoid having $x$ inside and outside the integral sign.

$\frac{dX}{dT} = (a-(b+c))X-aX^2 \Rightarrow \frac{dX}{(a-(b+c))X-aX^2} = dT$
$\Rightarrow \int\limits_{x0}^x\frac{dX}{(a-(b+c))X-aX^2} =\int\limits_0^tdT$
$\Rightarrow t=\frac{\ln(x)-\ln((a-(b+c))-ax)}{a-(b+c)}-\frac{\ln(x_0)-\ln((a-(b+c))-ax_0)}{a-(b+c)}$

Finally isolate $x$ to have $x=f(t,a,b,c)$

Comment: There is some mix up in your results when you do partial fractions.  I think you are missing an a in front of the second log term!!

Comment: I did forget the part with $x_0$ but i don't think i'm missing an $a$ (not according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28%28a-b-c%29x-ax%5E2%29)

Comment: Why hide carefully the core of the proof?